# Search view toolbar close icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I am using Search view in the toolbar. I am facing issue with the close icon. 
It is working as excepted on mobile but not working on Android tablets. On the tablet, it is showing in the middle of the action bar instead of right side.

As shown in below images:

On Mobile (Correct):

[image]

On Tablet (Incorrect):

[image]

My XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:title="Search" />
</menu>
```

My JAVA Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search_view_explore_ideas, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");

    ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notify_user_color));

    if (searchManager != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    }

    AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    try {
        Field mCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        mCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
        mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, R.drawable.cursor_for_search_view); //This sets the cursor resource ID to 0 or @null which will make it visible on white background
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: please post activity layout

Comment: Try  app:showAsAction="always" . And searchview width to "fill_parent"

Comment: Create a separate layout for tab layouts/large/your_activity.xml

Comment: oh, you're inflating it with a menu. I haven't done it like that before but if you wanna try you can inflate with a layout and anchor(align parent) end of the layout. Edit: in item there is  android:gravity = "end"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you try like this in your `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search_view_explore_ideas, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your onCreateOptionsMenu() try this for searchView after inflating menu,

searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreateOptionsMenu()
try following code for searchView after inflating menu,

SearchView searchView= (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Answer (score 0):

Try this on onCreateOptionsMenu

searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Answer (score 0):

In your OnCreateView 
make following change

```
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```